# Add text to navbar Bootstrap 3.3

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to add text to header of jumbotron template:

```
<div id="navbar" class="navbar-collapse collapse">
    <form class="navbar-form navbar-right">
        <div class="form-group">
            <input type="text" placeholder="Email" class="form-control">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <input type="password" placeholder="Password" class="form-control">
        </div>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Sign in</button>
        <p class="navbar-text">Right align-Text</p>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Sign up</button>
    </form>
</div><!--/.navbar-collapse -->
```

But it is not after Sign in button

[image]

I am newbee in html, could you help.

Comment: Could you add your CSS ?

Comment: I don't have my css, only bootstrapper css and jumbotron.css with:

body {
  padding-top: 50px;
  padding-bottom: 20px;
} .

Comment: Take a look at my answer then.

Comment: Thanks, I thought that navbar-text class is defined in bootstrap

Comment: You can overwrite it with your own CSS file

Answer (score 0):

Here you go, https://jsfiddle.net/wttn6sxs/2/

Just add this in your CSS :

```
.navbar-text {
    margin-top: 7.5px;
    margin-bottom: 7.5px;
    display: inline-block;
    float: initial;
}
```

This will fix your issue.